# How to use the sum query for specific rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a bit of a problem with my MYSQL query, here I am returning all the results to populate a league table.

The table looks like a bigger version of this

```
MEMBERS RESULTS TABLE
member_id      1   2   1   2
track_id       1   1   2   2
total_points  234 432 222 234
```

The SUM(total) is returning the SUM for all the total_points together no matter what the `member_id` is, when I need them to calculate just for where each `member_id` row is.

```
SELECT members.member_id, members.teamname, SUM(total_points)
FROM members, members_leagues, member_results
   WHERE members.member_id = members_leagues.member_id
     AND members_leagues.league_id = '45'
       AND member_results.track_id = '1'
          AND member_results.member_id = members_leagues.member_id
             AND members_leagues.start_race >= member_results.track_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT members.member_id, members.teamname, SUM(total_points)
FROM members, members_leagues, member_results
   WHERE members.member_id = members_leagues.member_id
     AND members_leagues.league_id = '45'
       AND member_results.track_id = '1'
          AND member_results.member_id = members_leagues.member_id
             AND members_leagues.start_race >= member_results.track_id 
GROUP BY members.memberID
```

Comment: Np :). if this solved your problem just mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

just add a [group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

```
GROUP BY members.member_id
```